# Redirect to URL with POST method in Asp.Net Core3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, .net-core

I am usig Asp.net core 3.1 and I must to redirect user to a url with Post Action, what should I do? is it possible?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RedirectTo()
{
    // do something to generate a url 
    // redirectUrl = "https://xx.com/?token=zzzzz"
    
    redirect and Post to redirectUrl //how ???????????????????  
}
```

Comment: You can't redirect to a POST method. What exactly are you thinking to POST here anyway?

Comment: I want to direct the user to the bank portal.
According to the bank document, I have to post 'redirectUrl' to the bank portal. I actually want to navigate user to this path by post action. is it possible???!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check here for more information as to why this is not supported](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect)

You can't really do it BUT, there is a clever workaround [here](https://gist.github.com/priore/7163408)

```
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();

            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.Append("<html>");
            s.AppendFormat("<body onload='document.forms[\"form\"].submit()'>");
            s.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", url);
            foreach (string key in data)
            {
                s.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{1}' />", key, data[key]);
            }
            s.Append("</form></body></html>");
            response.Write(s.ToString());
            response.End();
```

What this does, is create on html response with a form that will post a request to the required page with javascript.

You need to be in the same domain for this to work. If you redirect, then you can only do so with GET - parameters.

Comment: Thanks, But can you write your code clear or describe more? because I dont know where and how use your trick. thanks