# Redirect to external application POST method with json data in Asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, post, http-redirect

I need to create a Redirect application to receive the request and based on the request it will redirect to target uri with some additional data. The application should handle both `GET` and `POST` methods. For `POST` method it must support `ContentType: application/json.` I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315615/10857406) to redirect the `POST` uri and submit the data, but it doesn't support the content type application/json.

Now my code is,

```
      string url = "http://example.com/targeturi";
      NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
      data.Add("action", "redirectMock");
      HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Response;
      response.Clear();

      response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      s.Append("<html>");
      s.AppendFormat("<body onload='document.forms[\"form\"].submit()'>");
      s.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post' enctype='application/json'>", url);
      foreach (string key in data)
      {
        s.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{1}' />", key, data[key]);
      }
      s.Append("</form></body></html>");
      var body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s.ToString());
      await response.Body.WriteAsync(body);
```

And the target application reads request body like this, (target application code cannot be changed)

```
      var reqbody = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
      var parsedBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(reqbody);
```

Is there any workaround to redirect to post method with json data and `ContentType: application/json`?

Comment: Please clarify "with some additional data."

Comment: The enctype property of your form couldn't be application/json it should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded,multipart/form-data,text/plain

Comment: Thanks @RuikaiFeng. Yeah, it only supports these three types. but, my requirement is to post json data to the target uri. Is there any alternative solution to submit `JSON` data?

Comment: What you're doing right now is technically not redirecting, it's returning a page with some JS that then immediately triggers a new page load. It sounds like what you're trying to achieve isn't a redirect but a proxy, i.e your ASP.NET Core application acting as a proxy for another application. For that you can simply just create an endpoint that then creates a HTTP request in the background, adding the data from the original request as well as additional data.

Comment: Thanks @DiplomacyNotWar. Added some additional information

Comment: Thanks @MindSwipe. For `GET` Method, In ASP.NET core we will use `return Redirect("SomeURI");` But `POST` method Form submission may be the only option. Please let me know if there is an alternative solution